# Xamarin.IOS does not support running or debugging the previous built version of your project

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, maui

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl8z2.png)
[visual studio version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5R80Z.png)

my IOS Version is 15.6.1
i have been login to my Account Apple Developer, and i want to build to local IOS but this message shown (error). anyone have solution for this?

have been deleted bin obj clean solution and rebuild, but not solved

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, if you are building a `Xamarin iOS` project, try to change `Deployment Target` to `15.4` in the `Info.plist` file. If it is a `Maui` app, try to change the `Minimum Target iOS Framework` to `15.4` in the iOS Targets option.

If the above doesn't work, you can try to create an empty project in your Xcode to see if it can build and deploy to your iOS 15.6.1 device. If it still doesn't work, you may need to upgrade your Xcode to the latest version: `Xcode14.2` and another physical device with iOS `16.2`.

Hope it works for you!